# Como cambiar el fondo de un botón en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy tratando de cambiar el color de fondo a mi JButton en Java, pero solo cambia el color del borde. Aquí les dejo el código que estoy usando, alguien sabe si me falta algo o estoy haciendo algo mal? Gracias de antemano. Por cierto, el botón lo arrastre del cuadro de herramientas.

```
btnArrastra.setOpaque(true);
btnArrastra.setBackground(Color.blue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar combinando dos propiedades:

```
btnArrastra.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
btnArrastra.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
```

o en su caso utilizando RGB:

```
btnArrastra.setBackground(New Color(int, int, int));
```

Puedes también ver esta [Pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202938/8886566) para crear un boton con gradiente.