# Problemas al poner setBackground a un button Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, macos, jbutton

estoy probando Swing. Tengo este código:

```
public class Ventana extends JFrame {
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private JButton btnNewButton;
    public Ventana() {

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Hola Mundo");
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Otro label");
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        btnNewButton = new JButton("Mi botón");
        btnNewButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        btnNewButton.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
        btnNewButton.setOpaque(true);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

El resultado es esta imagen:

[image: Captura JFrame]

Por qué no muestra todo el color en el fondo del Button con nombre Mi botón?

Gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo.

Comment: ya probaste con `setOpaque()` en false?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como cambiar el fondo de un botón en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124680/como-cambiar-el-fondo-de-un-bot%c3%b3n-en-java)

Comment: Con el setOpaque en false no se ve nada de amarillo :(

Comment: En Windows funciona pero en OSX no. ¿Alguna solución para OSX?

Answer (score 0):

para solucionar esto, simplemente añade:

```
btnNewButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Espero que te sirva.